# How do I get the componentFactoryResolver to create an anchor with a RouterLink?

Tags: angular

I would like to dynamically add an anchor tag to a point on my page.

So far, I have something like this

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HTMLAnchorElement);

let cmpRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
cmpRef.instance.text = 'click here';
cmpRef.instance.routerlink = "/mylink"
```

However, cmpRef.instance.routerLink doesn't exist, probably because HTMLAnchorElement is the actual Html anchor tag and not the angular version which has the routerlink input on it.

What is the Angular anchor tag's component name in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Angular component for anchor tag.

If you want to implement it by yourself then it could be something like this:

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'router-link',
  template: `<a [routerLink]="routerLink">{{text}}</a>`
})
export class RouterLinkComponent {
  text: string;

  routerLink: string;
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(RouterLinkComponent);

let cmpRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
cmpRef.instance.text = 'click here';
cmpRef.instance.routerLink = '/about';
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/kqPd1rtN9XhmASEB1bGO)**

Comment: damn, yeah that's exactly what I've done. I just figured there was a better way of implementing this.